# Returning array of results from Firebase query

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using the `@react-native-firebase` wrapper to interact with Firebase's Firestore. I have a function which performs some querying to one of my collections and the intended response should be an Array object containing each found document.

My function currently looks like:

```js
export const backendCall = async => {
  let response = [] 
  firestore()
  .collection('collection')
  .where('id', '==', 1)
  .onSnapshot(documentSnapshot => {
    documentSnapshot.forEach(x => response.push(x.data())) 
  })
  return response
```

On my UI, I use a `react-native` `Button` component which calls this function `onPress`:

```js
<Button 
  title="get" 
  onPress={() => {
    backendCall().then(response => console.log(response)) 
  }}
/>
```

Using `console.log` I am able to observe the expected `Array` object (but with a "value below was evaluated just now" icon. If however, I change the `onPress` to `console.log(JSON.stringify(response))`, the `Array` object is empty.

I'm assuming this has something to do with the async calls but I can't quite figure out how to fix it. Would appreciate some pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're returning the response without waiting for the result from your firebase query. To wait for the response to arrive before returning, you can use Promise.

```js
export const backendCall = () => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        firestore()
            .collection('collection')
            .where('id', '==', 1)
            .onSnapshot(documentSnapshot => {
                const response = []
                documentSnapshot.forEach(x => response.push(x.data()))
                resolve(response)
            })
    })
}
```

You can use Array.map to make the for loop looks nicer.

```js
const response = documentSnapshot.map(x => x.data())
resolve(response)
```

Comment: That's very helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can also read `docs` from a `QuerySnapshot`:

```
export const backendCall = async () => {
  const qs = firestore().collection('collection').where('id', '==', 1).get()
  return qs.docs.map(x => x.data())
}
```